# How to safely assert a certain state from a typescript useReducer hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Let's imagine we have the following state with its reducer actions

```js
type User = {
    id: number
}

type LoginState = {
    user?: User,
    isLoggingIn: boolean,
    isLoggedIn: boolean,
    error?: Error
}

type LoginActions =
    | { type: 'START_LOGGING_IN' }
    | { type: 'SUCCESSFUL_LOG_IN', user: User }
    | { type: 'ERROR', error: Error }
    | { type: 'START_LOGGING_IN' }
```

If I want to consume this state from all my app, I'll surely need some react context solution. I'd prefer not to have any external dependencies used for this question.

However, after [some fsharp learning](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-making-illegal-states-unrepresentable/), this approach leads to impossible states being possible. For example, the state `isLoggedIn` could have an error if we make a mistake in the reducer.

The solution would be to make the LoginState a discriminated union type, but then as far as I've tested the typescript typings for the useReducer force me to have all the properties in a type, like in the example.

So, how is this problem normally solved? I know that the example I described is the standard approach, but then, whenever consuming the login state, I have to handle in every place the user non-existence, which I don't want. I'd like the most type-safe solution to this problem, so also no `type assertions` used please.

If I'm wrong in some assertions I've made please correct me, I'm quite confused with the front end stuff :S

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The most type safe approach is to define `LoginState` as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) of only valid reducer states. This gives you ability to define functions that handle only those union's constituent types they're designed for.

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL9k2W)

Though usually that's a lot hustle and most of the time developers are pretty happy with the type of `LoginState` as defined in your question.

Comment: Mmm, I see, the problem with that approach is that you have to still write a lot of useless fields for each state, which is not really scalable for more complex states.

I guess I was asking for some sort of state machine like Xstate, but then, why do the react docs recommend this approach for complex states?

Even more, why the useReducer doesn't accept a union of states with different shapes? The boolean flags where never really a clean solution to represent states.

Thank you for your link to the playground though

Comment: Well, you can cut some corners with interface inheritance but for complex states it gets messy pretty fast anyway.